# Multiple submit buttons with Formvalidation.io

Tags: javascript, forms, formvalidation-plugin, formvalidation.io

I have 2 submit buttons in my form:

```html
<button type="submit" name="save_and_stay">Save and stay</button>
<button type="submit" name="save">Save and get back</button>
```

Unfortunately, `name` values are not send to the server by formvalidation.io.

Seems related to what 'DefaultSubmit' plugin doc says :

> Do NOT use name="submit" or id="submit" for the Submit button

Is there any way to make it work?

Secondary question: is there any issue tracker for formvalidation.io?

Comment: you solved? I have the same problem too

Comment: @Vins yes I did, I'll write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: using `aspNetButton` attribute for SubmitButton plugin.

```js
    submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton({
        //-- make multiple submits work
        aspNetButton: true
    }),
```

And for the second question: no, formvalidation.io has no issue tracker but the developer answers to emails.